# How to add id to drawn ellipses?

Tags: c#, wpf, object

This is my code to draw a maximum of 3 ellipses on a drawing canvas, I would like to have properties to describe each object drawn (such as mass, velocity and id)
How do I create an id for each new object drawn in the loop so I can give each one different masses and velocities?

```
Ellipse ealswith = new Ellipse();
ealswith.Height = 70; // Setting height
ealswith.Width = 70;   // setting width 

for (int i = 0; i <= setOfEllipses.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
{
    if (this.drawingCanvas.Children.Count > 2) 
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Maximum number of objects have been drawn.");
        break;
    }

    if (setOfEllipses[i] == null)
    {
        if (this.drawingCanvas.Children.Count < 3)
        {
            setOfEllipses[i] = ealswith;
            drawingCanvas.Children.Add(ealswith);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you considered encapsulating this data into a class? It seems like it would be a suitable solution.

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms? WPF? ASP? ...?? __Always__ tag your question accordingly!

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two ways to do this:-

1. Use the Tag property of the ellipse to store the ID, or better still, create a class that contins the information you need (mass, velocity, etc) and store that object in the Tag property.
2. Extend the Ellipse class and the extra properties as derived members.

Comment: Indeed. These would be the most elegant options.